# Print ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, printing, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that contains Address objects.

How do I print the values of this ArrayList, meaning I am printing out the contents of the Array, in this case numbers.

I can only get it to print out the actual memory address of the array with this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < houseAddress.size(); i++) {   
    System.out.print(houseAddress.get(i));
}
```

Comment: do you want the address location in memory?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you mean. the arraylist is storing the address pointing to the array, and i want to print the contents of the array, but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: I tried to reword the question to make it clearer.

Comment: By Address, he mean House address. I think.

Comment: @dancooper93: Just add the complete declaration of `houseAddress` including the generics parameter to your question.

Comment: houseAddress is just the name of my ArrayList, it contains an address pointing to an Array which contains the actual numbers, I want to be able to print these numbers through the ArrayList.

Comment: Okay, I'm completely confused now. You say you have an `ArrayList`, which contains an address pointing to an Array. How did you obtain the address of the Array that you put in the `ArrayList`? In Java, you should not be able to get your hands on any raw pointers (at least not easily).

Comment: you can't point to memory locations in Java.

Comment: try including a larger code sample, that may help us infer the question.

Comment: Please, just give us the declaration of the `houseAddress` variable, and some sample code for the elements that it contains.

Comment: ok, in my contructor the line to declare my ArrayList is houseAddress = new ArrayList<Numbers>();     with Numbers being the name of the Array in my other class

Answer (score 142):

list.toString() is good enough.

The interface List does not define a contract for toString(), but the AbstractCollection base class provides a useful implementation that ArrayList inherits.

Comment: The same output is print by System.out.println(list);

Comment: list is houseAddress here: `Arrays.toString(houseAddress.toArray())`

Comment: AbstractCollection already overrides ```toString()``` to print the contents of its elements. So, just ```list.toString()``` prints the ```toString()``` of all its elements. This is true for all collections.

Answer (score 28):

Add `toString()` method to your `address` class then do

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(houseAddress));
```

Comment: This would only work for an array, not an array list. You can not provide `houseAddress` as an argument for `Arrays.toString()` because it is not of type Array.

Comment: in my opinion looping is only possible wayout here , if anyone knows better option please share.

Answer (score 26):

From what I understand you are trying to print an ArrayList of arrays and one way to display that would be

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(list.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 9):

since you haven't provide a custom implementation for `toString()` method it calls the default on which is going to print the address in memory for that object

**solution**
in your Address class override the `toString()` method like this

```
public class Address {

int addressNo ; 
....
....
...

protected String toString(){
    return Integer.toString(addressNo);
}
```

now when you call

```
houseAddress.get(i)  in the `System.out.print()` method like this
```

`System.out.print( houseAddress.get(i) )` the `toString()` of the `Address` object will be called

Answer (score 9):

You can simply give it as:

```
System.out.println("Address:" +houseAddress);
```

Your output will look like `[address1, address2, address3]`

This is because the class ArrayList or its superclass would have a toString() function overridden.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

assium that you have a numbers list like that

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

if you print the  list

```
//method 1
// Conventional way of printing arraylist
for (int number : numbers) {
    System.out.print(number);
}

//method 2
// Lambda Expression to print arraylist
numbers.forEach((Integer value) -> System.out.print(value));

//method 3
// Lambda Expression to print arraylist
numbers.forEach(value -> System.out.print(value));


//method 4
// Lambda Expression (method reference) to print arraylist
numbers.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you saying that `ArrayList` is storing addresses of arrays because that is what is returning from the `toString` call, or because that's actually what you're storing?

If you have an `ArrayList` of arrays (e.g.

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
houseAddress.add(arr);
```

Then to print the array values you need to call `Arrays.deepToString`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < houseAddress.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(houseAddress.get(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public void printList(ArrayList<Address> list){
    for(Address elem : list){
        System.out.println(elem+"  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not different from OPs current code. The problem remains.

Answer (score 3):

Put `houseAddress.get(i)` inside the brackets and call `.toString()` function: i.e Please see below

```
for(int i = 0; i < houseAddress.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print((houseAddress.get(i)).toString());
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Goose i do not get your question quite clear, what do you mean?

Comment: call to .toString() is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understood the notion of addresses (I am assuming houseAddress here), but if you are looking for way a to print the ArrayList, here you go:

```
System.out.println(houseAddress.toString().replaceAll("\\[\\]", ""));
```

Answer (score 3):

Since **Java 8**, you can use *forEach()* method from *Iterable* interface.
 
It's a default method. As an argument, it takes an object of class, which implements functional interface *Consumer*. You can implement Consumer locally in three ways:
With **annonymous class**:

```
houseAddress.forEach(new Consumer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
});
```

**lambda expression**:

```
houseAddress.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

or by using **method reference**:

```
houseAddress.forEach(System.out::print);
```

This way of printing works for all implementations of *Iterable* interface.
All of them, gives you the way of defining how the elements will be printed, whereas *toString()* enforces printing list in one format.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way to print an ArrayList is by using toString

```
List<String> a=new ArrayList<>();
    a.add("111");
    a.add("112");
    a.add("113");
    System.out.println(a.toString());
```

### Output

[111, 112, 113]

Comment: I donot think toString is required in this case. ArrayList overrides AbstractCollection class and hence it will take care of printing the values

Answer (score 2):

This helped to me:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codeLangArray.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Iterator. It is the most simple and least controvercial thing to do over here. Say `houseAddress` has values of data type `String`

```
Iterator<String> iterator = houseAddress.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Note : You can even use an enhanced for loop for this as mentioned by me in another answer

Comment: p.s. it is least controvercial because you are not doing any unnecesary conversions over here like converting ArrayList to Array and then converting it to string to print it

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Moyen> list = new ArrayList<Moyen>();
        Moyen m1 = new Moyen();
        m1.setCodification("c1");
        m1.setCapacityManager("Avinash");
        Moyen m2 = new Moyen();
        m2.setCodification("c1");
        m2.setCapacityManager("Avinash");
        Moyen m3 = new Moyen();
        m3.setCodification("c1");
        m3.setCapacityManager("Avinash");

        list.add(m1);
        list.add(m2);
        list.add(m3);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even use an enhanced for loop or an iterator like:

```
for (String name : houseAddress) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

You can change it to whatever data type `houseAddress` is and it avoids unnecessary conversions

Answer (score 1):

if you make the @Override public String toString() as comments,
you will have the same results as you did. 
But if you implement your toString() method, it will work.

public class PrintingComplexArrayList {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List houseAddress = new ArrayList();
    insertAddress(houseAddress);
    printMe1(houseAddress);
    printMe2(houseAddress);
}

private static void insertAddress(List address)
{
    address.add(new Address(1));
    address.add(new Address(2));
    address.add(new Address(3));
    address.add(new Address(4));
}
private static void printMe1(List address)
{
    for (int i=0; i<address.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(address.get(i));
}

private static void printMe2(List address)
{
    System.out.println(address);
}
```

}

class Address{
    private int addr;
    public Address(int i)
    {
        addr = i;
    }

```
@Override public String toString()
{
    Integer iAddr = new Integer (addr);
    return iAddr.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a getter in House address class and then use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < houseAddress.size(); i++) {   
    System.out.print(houseAddress.get(i)**.getAddress()**);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review the [answer] section and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use print format if you just want to print the element on the console.

```
for(int i = 0; i < houseAddress.size(); i++) {   
    System.out.printf("%s", houseAddress.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `houseAddress.get(i)` is an `ArrayList` you can add `toString()` after the `ArrayList` :

```
for(int i = 0; i < houseAddress.size(); i++) {   
    System.out.print(houseAddress.get(i).toString());
}
```

A general example:

```
ArrayList<Double> a = new ArrayList();
a.add(2.);
a.add(32.);
System.out.println(a.toString());
// output
// [2.0, 32.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple code of add the value in ArrayList and print the ArrayList Value

```
public class Samim {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Declare list
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // Add value in list
    list.add("First Value ArrayPosition=0");
    list.add("Second Value ArrayPosition=1");
    list.add("Third Value ArrayPosition=2");
    list.add("Fourth Value ArrayPosition=3");
    list.add("Fifth Value ArrayPosition=4");
    list.add("Sixth Value ArrayPosition=5");
    list.add("Seventh Value ArrayPosition=6");

    String[] objects1 = list.toArray(new String[0]);

    // Print Position Value
    System.err.println(objects1[2]);

    // Print All Value
    for (String val : objects1) {
        System.out.println(val);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**JSON**

An alternative Solution could be converting your list in the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format and print the Json-String. The advantage is a well formatted and readable Object-String without a need of implementing the `toString()`. Additionaly it works for any other `Object` or `Collection` on the fly.

Example using Google's [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson):

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

...
public static void printJsonString(Object o) {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    /*
     * Some options for GsonBuilder like setting dateformat or pretty printing
     */
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    String json= gson.toJson(o);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add toString() method to your class
2. houseAddress.forEach(System.out::println);

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an "Enhanced for loop" I had to do this solution for a scenario in which the **arrayList** was coming from a *class object*

changing the String datatype to the appropriate datatype or class object as desired.

```
ArrayList<String> teamRoster = new ArrayList<String>();

// Adding player names
teamRoster.add("Mike");
teamRoster.add("Scottie");
teamRoster.add("Toni");

System.out.println("Current roster: ");

for (String playerName : teamRoster) {
   System.out.println(playerName);
   // if using an object datatype, you may need to use a solution such as playerName.getPlayer()
}
```