# my array to list conversion is not working, and i am not getting why?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

program counts the frequency of max number but the conversion of array into list gives list=[I@7852e922
instead of what it should actually return.

```
static int birthdayCakeCandles(int[] ar) {
        Arrays.sort(ar);
        for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(ar[i]);  
        }

        int max=ar[ar.length-1];
        System.out.println("\n"+max);
        List list = Arrays.asList(ar);
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));  
        }
        int sol=Collections.frequency(list,max);
        return sol;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[]={1,2,3,4,4,2};

    int ans=birthdayCakeCandles(arr);
    System.out.print(ans);
    }
```

the output that this gives is:

```
122344
4
[I@7852e922
0
```

which is not correct as the array to list conversion is not taking place in the right way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265719/print-arraylist)

Comment: "is not working", can you be more specific about that?

Comment: Change `int arr[]` to `Integer arr[]` if you want Arrays.asList to produce a List of Integer (and not a List of int[])

Comment: @gauravgupta if you got the answer please accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

From [Arrays.asList(int[]) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422025/arrays-aslistint-not-working)

> When you pass an array of primitives (`int[]` in your case) to Arrays.asList, it creates a `List<int[]>` with a single element - the array itself.
>
> The signature of `asList` is `List<T>` [asList(T...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-). A primitive can't replace a generic type parameter. Therefore, when you pass to this method an `int[]`, the entire `int[]` array replaces `T` and you get a `List<int[]>`. On the other hand, when you pass an `Integer[]` to that method, `Integer` replaces `T` and you get a `List<Integer>`.

Thats why in your case it `Collections.frequency(list,max)` was returning 0.

Change your function like below:

```
static int birthdayCakeCandles(int[] ar) {
        Arrays.sort(ar);
        for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(ar[i]);  
        }

        int max=ar[ar.length-1];
        // convert your int ar to Integer List
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(ar).boxed()// Stream<Integer>
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("\n"+max);
        int sol=Collections.frequency(list,max);
        return sol;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Arrays.asList** will not work as you expect.

From **Java 8** onwards:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(ar).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: connecting question why does Arrays.asList not work in the way it is expected?
In this very situation

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use the popular Arrays.asList to convert it directly, because boxing issue.

For this to work, you can make below changes in the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer arr[]={1,2,3,4,4,2};

        int ans=birthdayCakeCandles(arr);
        System.out.print(ans);
}
```